Popup Form close when select tag one option is selected

In this popup form when i select an option from the given options, popup form automatically closes.
I used a component from antd design i read the documentation but i couldn't find anything useful
import React from 'react';
import { Select } from 'antd';

const { Option } = Select;

const MultiSelect = ({ items, selectedItems, onChange, placeholder, size="middle", labelOutside }) => {
  const handleChange = (value) => {
    onChange(value); // Pass the selected value to the parent component
  };
  return (
    <div style={{ width: '100%', maxWidth: '400px', margin: '0 auto' }}>
      {labelOutside && <label >{placeholder}</label>}
      <Select
      className='mt-2'
        mode="multiple"
        size={size}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        defaultValue={selectedItems}
        value={selectedItems} // Use value instead of defaultValue
        onChange={handleChange} // Call handleChange function
        style={{ width: '100%' }}
      >
        {items.map(item => (
          <Option key={item.id} value={item.name}>{item.name}</Option>
        ))}
      </Select>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MultiSelect;


This is the component i used
const handleSelectionChange = (selectedItemNames) => {
        
        // Assuming 'items' uses 'name' as a unique key; adjust logic if 'id' should be used instead
        const updatedSelection = users.filter(user => selectedItemNames.includes(user.name));
        setSelectedUsers(updatedSelection);
        console.log("Selected Users: ", updatedSelection);
      };

<MultiSelect
                        items={users}
                        selectedItems={selectedUsers.map(user => user.name)}
                        onChange={handleSelectionChange}
                        placeholder="Select Categories"
                        labelOutside={true}
                      />

this the code that i used in the form to get the component and handlechange
I tried reading antd design documentation but couldnt find anything useful,
chatgpt answers also didnt match the requirements.
I need to understand why this happens and how to fix this issue
for this project im using

nextJs 13
antd design


To prevent the popup form from automatically closing when selecting an option, you can utilize the dropdownMatchSelectWidth prop of the Select component from antd. Setting it to false will prevent the dropdown from automatically closing upon selection. dropdownMatchSelectWidth={false}

Pass getPopupContainer={(node) => node.parentNode)} to Select component.

@MuhammadNoumanRafique your technique works nicely
